# Creating PayPal account isn't optiona

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm using WooCommerce, with two plugins, PayPal checkout gateway, and yith checkout gateway, although in my PayPal account in web preferences I'm activating the 'optional PayPal account', and in both plugins setting , the chosen checkout style is 'billing non-paypal account' every time I try it I get redirected to login in to PayPal or create an account.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

The feature you mention, 'PayPal account optional', exists so you have the ability to only accept payments from people with an account (when set to 'No').

If set to 'Yes', payments without an account can are possible. But whether that possibility will be offered to a particular buyer in a particular PayPal checkout depends on very many factors, which you do not control.

The only way to have some guarantee of a guest method being offered is to show a credit card form before the buyer reaches a PayPal page, using the black 'Debit or Credit Card' button that is part of Smart Payment Buttons. You can see an example of that here: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

WooCommerce's newest PayPal module has an option to toggle on this type of checkout flow (Smart Payment Buttons)

Comment: Can you tell me please those factors

Comment: PayPal makes the final determination, so the criteria is their own, but things like the location of the buyer and seller and the countries and IP addresses involved are some of the factors considered